# Detect first letter in textbox then appears in gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, gridview, textbox

I'm a newbie in programming. How can I search the employee name by the first letter and display all those name which starts from eg: A then it should get display in data grid view? Currently, my code just detect 2 letters in textbox, then display in grid view. I want it detect the first letter. Here is my code:

```
private void textBoxName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    con.Open();
    adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "select name, empno, workno from m_employee where name like '%" + 
        textBoxName.Text + "%' and not [recsts] = 'R' order by empno", con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();

    if (textBoxName.Text != null)
    {
        dataGridView1.Visible = true;
    }

    if (textBoxName.Text == "")
    {
        dataGridView1.Visible = false;
    }

}

private void textBoxName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxName.Text = textBoxName.Text.TrimEnd();

    if (textBoxName.Text == "")
    {
        dataGridView1.Visible = false;
    }

    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
        string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", textBoxName.Text);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

            textBoxName.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["name"].Value.ToString();
            textBoxEmplNo.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["empno"].Value.ToString();
            textBoxWorkNo.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["workno"].Value.ToString();

        string selectSql = "select icnum, empno, passport, deptno, section from m_employee where workno=@workno";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workno", textBoxWorkNo.Text);

        bool isDataFound = false;

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (read.Read())
                {
                    isDataFound = true;

                    textBoxICPass.Text = (read["icnum"].ToString());
                    textBoxPassport.Text = (read["passport"].ToString());
                    textBoxDept.Text = (read["deptno"].ToString());
                    textBoxSection.Text = (read["section"].ToString());

                    string imgFilePath = @"C:\Users\hamizah\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\EV\photo\" + textBoxEmplNo.Text + ".jpg";
                    if (File.Exists(imgFilePath))
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imgFilePath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Display message that No such image found
                        // MessageBox.Show("No Image Found");
                        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\hamizah\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\EV\photo\No-image-found.jpg");
                    }


                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Off-topic but important, Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Do use parametrized queries.

Comment: You should use `Trim` instead of `TrimEnd` if you don't want any leading whitespace

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the first letter of your specific text, you can do one of the following approaches to do so:

```
// Access the first character by it's index
var letter = YourTextBox.Text[0];

// Access the first letter via the Substring() method
var letter = YourTextBox.Text.Substring(0, 1);
```

**Off-topic: Consider Parameterized Queries**

Additionally, you *should not* use string concatenation when building your queries as it leaves you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Consider instead using parameterized queries, which should keep you protected from those and may make your code a bit more readable:

```
// Build your query using parameters
var query = "SELECT ... WHERE Name LIKE @letter AND ...";

// Build your adapter to execute
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);

// Add your parameter
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@letter", letter + "%");

// Execute it here
```

Comment: that code should be in `private void textBoxName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)`?? Sorry i'm still in learning process in programming.

Comment: The first could really be applied to either depending on what you wanted to accomplish (i.e. either only include the first character when querying or update the contents after it changes and only store the first character). If you are only ever concerned about the first character being used, you might consider setting the [`TextBox.MaxLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property on your textbox to ensure that it never stored more than a single character, which would avoid you having to do anything extra.

Comment: I already try it but not work. I want the grid view automatically appears when I enter the first letter. Because currently, the grid view only automatically appears when I enter two letters.

Comment: If you want to handle if the GridView appears or not, consider using `dataGridView1.Visible = string.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(textBoxName.Text);` in both locations. This would ensure that your grid only appears if there is at least one non-space character within your textbox (e.g. it will toggle as expected).

Comment: Hi, it work! BUT when i double press backspace, it appears gridview :(

Comment: Oops. Minor typo, you'll want to negate that (i.e. only display the grid when it is NOT empty) using `dataGridView1.Visible = !string.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(textBoxName.Text)`.

Comment: it works! thank you very much BUT after I click the cell in gridview, it have error. The value in gridview not display in textbox.